# Strange values displayed in Xcode debugger

Tags: ios, xcode, swift, debugging, xcode7

I'm currently using Xcode version 7.2.1, and I'm getting weird values displayed for most values in the debugger. The weird thing is it's always the same value. Other than a few values, all variables are listed as containing the value "00:30:00". The best way to show this is to give you an example.

[image: strange values in Xcode debuger]

I have tried restarting Xcode, clean and build, re-booting, and even re-installing Xcode, but I can't seem to escape this weird value. If I put in print statements, all the values show up correctly in the console. Is there any way I can get them to be correct in the debugger? Thanks.

Edit:
This is kind of interesting. If I move the mouse pointer over one of the entries, you can see that it displays "00:30:00", but if I inspect the value, it displays the correct date value.

[image]

Comment: are you running the app in `release` mode?

Comment: What's the code look like for the dictionary?

Comment: brother please check response in rest client or postman. if it is same as above image then need to check from your API side other wise check your JSON parsing file you had ever use

Comment: This is the code for the dictionary: `text`// Form URL-Encoded Body
        let params = [
            "timeoff_id": "\(0)",
            "person_role_id": "\(kPersonRoleId)",
            "start_date": startDate,
            "end_date": endDate
        ]

Comment: `// Form URL-Encoded Body  
        let params = [  
            "timeoff_id": "\(0)",  
            "person_role_id": "\(kPersonRoleId)",  
            "start_date": startDate,  
            "end_date": endDate  
        ]`

Comment: Sorry. Can't seem to figure out what the markup is for a line break on here. Docs say 2 spaces, but no luck.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I finally figured it out! I must have typed something in the "Edit Summary Format..." popup. It took it as a literal format string and displayed it for all string values from thereafter. Once I removed that, everything went back to normal.