# Strange Xcode behaviour

Tags: ios, xcode8

I am about to raise this as a bug with apple support but it takes a long time to get any response from them so ... I wanted to ask here.

Debugging an app where i use some dateTime conversions between timezones.
I get the following strange behavior and I wonder if anyone else has seen this and knows how to fix it.

Xcode 8.3.2

You can see that the GMTDate is displaying 2 completely different date/time values ( they aren't even related values) and it is difficult to know which one is correct.
I have restarted Xcode /computer, etc, but still the same!

Screenshot attached:[image]

```
- (NSString*) convertToDeviceTime:(NSString*) GMTDate {

//create the formatter for parsing
NSDateFormatter *df = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
[df setTimeZone:[NSTimeZone timeZoneWithAbbreviation:@"GMT"]];
[df setDateFormat:@"yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss"];

//parsing the string and converting it to NSDate
NSDate *myGMTDate = [df dateFromString: GMTDate];

//create the formatter for the output
NSDateFormatter *out_df = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
[df setTimeZone:[NSTimeZone systemTimeZone]];
[out_df setDateFormat:@"yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss"];

//output the date
NSString *myDeviceDate =[out_df stringFromDate:myGMTDate];
NSLog(@"the date is %@",myDeviceDate);
return myDeviceDate;
}
```

new screenshot below - this has to be something wrong with Xcode, 
the real value of 'token' shows in the quick look, but the debugger window shows it as a date! Weird. I have restarted the Mac, still the same.

[image]

Update: It is happening with all NSString variables. As soon as I write a value to them, the debugger window shows them with the same date value. If I print them to the console or NSLog, then the values are shown correctly.

Comment: Can you add this piece of code? So that we can also check.

Comment: The double display occurs on the call to the method - so the argument (GMTDate) is showing 2 different values simultaneously in Xcode debugger (see screenshot) -the method call is just passing in a date string as the argument.

Comment: Show your code that is making the call. Are you *sure* it is sending an `NSString`? It seems very, very odd that using Quick Look on an NSString would show two different values - particularly what you are showing here...

Comment: @DonMag Yes it is definitely an NSString. I have added another screenshot! It is happening to EVERY NSString and showing them all to have the same Date value in the debugger, but the correct value shows in the Quick look.

Comment: Well, I can't imagine I will come up with an answer, but I am curious... If you reboot + clean derived data + start a new, empty project and add a simple string variable, do you see the same issue? Do you see it if you run on the simulator and on device? It almost *looks* like the debugger has some weird "stuck to a memory address" pointer...

Comment: @DonMag - I just loaded a completely different and finished project and it is doing exactly the same thing and showing the same weird date for all NSStrings in the debug windows so this is an Xcode problem. I have raised it with Apple and I will  let u know the outcome.

Comment: @DonMag, found it!. I had inadvertently typed something in the "Edit summary Format" popup window when debugging. I will answer my own question and attach a screenshot for anyone who is interested. Thanks for your input. Made me think about it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the culprit.
In the debugger the "Edit Summary Format" popup I had somehow inadvertently pasted this date value, and it was showing this for all NSString values.

FYI:It is NOT project specific, so when I loaded another project, it kept that "Edit Summary Format" string and applied it to all NSStrings.

Kudos to an older SO post here: [Strange values displayed in Xcode debugger](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35763465/strange-values-displayed-in-xcode-debugger)

Screenshots attached!

[image]

[image]